# How to use split() in velocity template?

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to split a string in velocity context to get an array in return like following--

```
   #if($stringValue.split("::")[1].length()==0)
       //some code
```

But it does not work for velocity.I am getting a parser error which is unable to compile []

So,how can I implement this logic in velocity???

Answer (score 0):

Using velocity 1.7 and possibly below this can be done using the String `split()` method.
Unlike it's Java counterpart for special characters one doesn't need to escape the forward slash (.e.g `"\\|"`).

```
#set ($myString = “This|is|my|dummy|text”) 

#set ($myArray = $myString.split("\|")) or
#set ($myArray = $myString.split('\|')) or
#set ($myArray = $myString.split("[|]"))
```

Note 1: To get the size of the array use: `$myArray.size()`

Note 2: To get actual values use `$myArray.get(0)` or `$myArray[0]` … etc

*Suggestion: one could use beforehand*  `#if ($myString.indexOf(‘|’)) ... #end`