# How get first element of string array in jira velocity?

Tags: jira, velocity

I'm new in velocity and need help.
I have com.atlassian.jira.user.RemoteUser and remoteUser.getDisplayName() returns string which I want to split around matches of the given regular expression. And then get first element of String array, but unfortunately I have:

`#set ($userName = $remoteUser.getDisplayName().split(" "))`

`$userName, Hello!`

And have [Ljava.lang.String;@74a70acb as I can understand it is String array.

But if I try try get
`#set ($userName = $remoteUser.getDisplayName().split(" ")[0])`

`$userName, Hello!`

I have

org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "[" at getEncodedBodyFromContent[line 1, column 58] Was expecting one of:
    <RPAREN> ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...
    "-" ...
    "+" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "%" ...
    <LOGICAL_AND> ...
    <LOGICAL_OR> ...
    <LOGICAL_LT> ...
    <LOGICAL_LE> ...
    <LOGICAL_GT> ...
    <LOGICAL_GE> ...
    <LOGICAL_EQUALS> ...
    <LOGICAL_NOT_EQUALS> ...
    <DOT> ...

If I try  `#set ($userName = $remoteUser.getDisplayName().split(" ")).get(0))` then I get null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Velocity 1.6.4 is more than ten years old and doesn't support arrays.

Velocity 1.7 was released in November 2010 and does supports arrays.

Someone, somewhere, should upgrade something (FYI current version is Velocity 2.2 ...).

Comment: Sorry, but it's typo in my question. Actually I have enough braces in expression, so I can't understand why I have org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "[" at getEncodedBodyFromContent[line 1, column 58]

Comment: @Duxa Which version of Velocity are you using? With just this simple line, I don't have any parsing problem with 1.7 or 2.2.

Comment: I found velocity-1.6.4-atlassian-7.jar

Comment: Here was the same question and no descision https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776820/how-to-use-split-in-velocity-template

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but `$string.split(" ")` command doesn't work. After that I thought I had String array, but after `$userName = $remoteUser.getDisplayName().split(" ").get($index)` I had null pointer exception.
Solution which helped was using `indexOf()` and `substring()` commands like this:

```
#set ($userName = $remoteUser.getDisplayName())
#set ($index = $userName.indexOf(' '))
#set ($surname = $userName.substring(0, $index))
#set ($index = $index + 1)
#set ($name = $userName.substring($index))
```